# Can't start fresh WSO2 install, NullPointerException error

Tags: wso2, redhat, rhel

I'm trying to startup wso2 identity server (version 5.10.0) using this:

```
[root@ethosdev2 wso2is-5.10.0]# sh bin/wso2server.sh -Dsetup
```

And get the following error:

```
[2023-06-19 10:27:06,190] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.internal.ConsentManagerComponent} - Error while activating ConsentManagerComponent. java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.util.ConsentDBInitializer.createConsentDatabase(ConsentDBInitializer.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.internal.ConsentManagerComponent.initializeConsentDB(ConsentManagerComponent.java:336)
    at org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.internal.ConsentManagerComponent.activate(ConsentManagerComponent.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

I'm really not sure how to fix this and was wondering if someone had some insight on what I can do to mitigate it. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: no graphical interface?

Comment: Start the server without the -Dsetup option?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity server deprecated using -DSetup to create the database automatically.
Refer this: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/changing-to-postgresql/#changing-the-default-datasource

Since WSO2 Identity Server is shipped with an embedded H2 database for storing data, you don't need to create the tables manually. But if you are going to use another database please refer appropriate https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/working-with-databases/#changing-the-default-databases.

Comment: Thank you. I have the eis_config.properties file set for Oracle and we did run the Oracle.sql scripts in the dbscripts directory. I didn't know that Dsetup was depreciated, it's still in the instructions from our vendor for setting up the app that we're trying to setup.